# Convert string to list of ints

Tags: dart

I have a string like this `"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 23, 54"`

I can do this by first converting it to list of string

```
List<String> list = str.split(",");
```

Then I have to loop the list and cast it to int.
Is it possible to convert the above string to List<int> in one line?

Edit 1:

I tried

```
List<int> ints = "1,2,3".split(",").map((i) => int.parse(i));
```

But I got 'MappedListIterable<String, int>' is not a subtype of type 'List'

Edit 2:

I found the solution. But I am not very clear.

```
List<int> ints = "1,2,3".split(",").map((i) => int.parse(i)).toList();
```

This solves the problem.
But what is the difference between adding toList() and not adding toList() in dart? Can someone explain please?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, you edited wrongly. It must be `string to List<int>`. In one line it can be converted to List easily by using the split method alone.

Comment: I hadn't edited that (I only removed the tag from the title, see https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66742600/revisions), but SO interprets things in angle brackets as HTML tags, but sometimes they are only converted on a subsequent edit, not on the initial post. I fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` method returns an *iterable*, not a list. It is *lazy*, so if you follow `map(...)` with `.first`, it will only convert the first element.

If you add `.toList()`, the you eagerly extract all the values from the iterable and create a list containing those values. Since you were asking for a list, you need to do this (an iterable is not necessarily a list).

Another one-liner would be:

```dart
List<int> ints = [for (var n in string.split(",")) int.parse(n)];
```

Alternatively, you can piggy-back on JSON decoding and do:

```dart
import "dart:convert";
...
list<int> ints = jsonDecode("[$string]");
```

Answer (score 3):

When using the Map method, it actually returns a MappedIterable (in this case a MappedListIterable) ([The documentation for this](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Iterable/map.html)) instance instead of List, so you need to cast it into a list instance.

That's why adding **toList()** is working because it actually converts to MappedListIterable into a List.

```dart
List<int> ints = "1,2,3".split(",").map((i) => int.parse(i)).toList();
```